# On screen resize: the previous screen width and height are in current extent returned from vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR

Tags: android, android-ndk, vulkan

I am writing a game for **Android** using the **Java** for the user interface and **C++** with the NDK for the render thread.  It uses **Vulkan** if available and otherwise uses **OpenGL ES**.  This bug occurs in **Vulkan** only.

There are a variety of reasons that the surface would be resized in the game.  An example is if a user is using the app in split screen mode, then moves to full screen mode.  For this case, I do not shut the entire app down and restart, rather I handle the resize myself via a call to `SurfaceHolder.Callback.surfaceChanged`.

When the surface is resized, I get a call to `SurfaceHolder.Callback.surfaceChanged`.  I pass the event to my C++ render thread.  The render thread waits for the device to become idle (by calling `vkDeviceWaitIdle`), then destroys the swapchain, depth image, render pass, graphics pipeline, frame buffers, and swapchain commands.  When it recreates the swapchain, it calls: `vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR` to get the current extent for the surface and passes the current extent into the `vkCreateSwapchainKHR` through `VkSwapchainCreateInfoKHR.imageExtent`.  Immediately after recreating the swapchain, updating the perspective matrix, etc, I draw a frame.

My problem is that the `VkSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR.currentExtent` comes back from `vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR` with the previous surface size.  This problem only happens if nothing is going on in the game and no new frame is drawn for a while.

I can fix this problem by passing in the values for the width and height received by `SurfaceHolder.Callback.surfaceChanged` to the render thread and then down to the swapchain recreation.  But I think this is the wrong solution.  Why isn't `currentExtent` the size of the surface like it says in the docs?  `SurfaceHolder.Callback.surfaceChanged` is supposed to get called after all changes to the surface occurred.

I can also fix the issue by drawing a frame before recreating the swapchain.  But I feel that this is also the wrong solution unless I understand why this is happening.  Do I have to do something other than wait for the device to become idle before recreating the swapchain?

I have the validation layers enabled (and know they are working) and they report nothing.

Let me know if you need any more information.  Thanks for all your help.